# Getting rid of GNU Emacs's menu bar in terminal windows

Tags: linux, terminal, debian, emacs

How to get rid of Emacs's menu bar in terminal windows?

The standard answer is to put

```
(when (not (display-graphic-p))
  (menu-bar-mode -1))
```

in `init.el`.  However, this solution is not good, because all it does is
remove the menu bar after the fact.  You can still see it for a split
second.  It's very annoying.

Looking at the source code in `startup.el` I don't see an obvious solution
to this problem.  I think the only way is to use `before-init-hook`.  Maybe
this could do the trick?

```
(add-hook 'before-init-hook
          (lambda ()
            (setq emacs-basic-display t)))
```

But this hook is run before `init.el` and other init files are evaluated, so
how is one supposed to use it?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX, BSD? Which version?

Comment: Thanks, I'm using Debian GNU/Linux, the "testing" version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that this seems to depend on the size of the terminal window of all things. I tested on `terminator` and `xterm` and in both cases, increasing the size of the window stopped the menu bar from appearing while `emacs` was loading. Go figure. Specifically, a terminal width of >=88 seems to stop the menu buffer from appearing. Height appears to be irrelevant. You could, therefore, change the default size of your terminal window and that might solve your issue.

This is not an ideal solution, obviously, and does not help if you are running from a tty not a terminal emulator but it may be the best you'll get without delving deep into the `emacs` source code which I imagine you won't find worth the effort to get rid of such a minor annoyance.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that there is a way to suppress it initially, at least the momentary appearance you mention. You might try customizing `initial-frame-alist`, but I have a doubt about that having any effect here.  I tried `emacs -nw -f menu-bar-mode`, and that turns off the menu-bar, but again, it  first appears momentarily.