# How can I disable the icon bar in Emacs GUI under OSX?

Tags: macos, emacs

Is there a way to get rid of this tool/icon bar in Emacs GUI under OSX?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't use OSX so the details might be different for your machine but on my Linux I have two options.

1. The GUI way:

   [image]

   This is not persistent across sessions though, next time you open `emacs`, the bar will be back.
2. The `emacs` way; just add this line to your `$HOME/.emacs` file:

   ```
   (tool-bar-mode -1)
   ```

   Now, every time you open `emacs` the bar will appear briefly but will be gone by the time `emacs` has finished initializing and is ready for use. I have previously tried to get this to work better, without having the bar appear at all, for the menu-bar but [could not find](https://superuser.com/q/664431/151431) a better way.